# What's the best practice for async APIs that return futures on Scala?

Tags: design, scala, async

I have started a project to write an [async PostgreSQL driver](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-netty) on Scala and to be async, I need to accept callbacks and use futures, but then accepting a callback **and** a future makes the code cumbersome because you always have to send a callback even if it is useless.

Here's a test:

```
"insert a row in the database" in {

  withHandler {
    (handler, future) =>
      future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      handler.sendQuery( this.create ){ query =>  }.get( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
      handler.sendQuery( this.insert ){ query =>  }.get( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS ).rowsAffected === 1
  }

}
```

Sending the empty callback is horrible but I couldn't find a way to make it optional or anything like that, so right now I don't have a lot of ideas on how this external API should look like.

It could be something like:

```
handler.sendQuery( this.create ).addListener { query => println(query) }
```

But then again, I'm not sure how people are organizing API's in this regard. Providing examples in other projects would also be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking async and futures in Scala, it is imperative that you read [SIP-14: Futures and Promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html). There were also some extensive discussions about it on the SIP mailing list, which is a google group, so you can find its archives.

Answer (score 2):

No, you just use futures *and don't call `get` on them unless absolutely necessary*. Instead, you add callbacks to the futures and transform and compose futures with combinators. See [Twitter Util futures](http://twitter.github.com/util/util-core/target/site/doc/main/api/com/twitter/util/Future.html) and [Akka futures](http://akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/futures.html).